# IndexError: list index out of range when checking a json body

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm a bit new to coding in general, and I'm trying to check if a nested list in json has data in the "key2" in order to create some logs.

So the body is something like this:

```py
body = {
"key1": "value1",
"key2": ["value2"]
}

#or 

body = {
"key1": "value1",
"key2": []
}

#or

body = {
"key1": "value1"
}
```

I need to only create a log if the **"key2": ["value2"]**, but "value2" can be a random string of words. So far the code works ok for the 1º body and the 3º, but it fails if **"key2": []** and it gives the error "IndexError: list index out of range". I haven't found a way to solve this, can anybody help?

```py
import json
import logging

body = {...}

if "key2" in body and len(body["key2"][0]) > 0:
    logging.warning("data ok")
else:
    logging.warning("no value")
```

Comment: try `if "key2" in body and len(body.get("key2")) > 0`

Comment: Or just `if len(body.get("key2", "")) > 0` to avoid the redundant `in`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean `len(body["key2"]) > 0`.

Also, you can simplify the entire condition to just

```
if body.get('key2', []):
```

If `key2` does not exist `[]` will be returned, and an empty list evaluates to `False`.

Better yet, since we don't use `len` at all now we can simply use `None` which is the default value that `.get` returns:

```
if body.get('key2'):
```

Comment: The default return value from `.get()` is `None`, which is also falsey. There's no need to create a list.

Comment: @Barmar Of course. I guess I used `[]` because I still had the `len` check in mind...

Comment: Thanks for the help, it got my code working fine.